# Opencv_world build error with cmake from the git source

Tags: visual-studio, opencv3.0

So, is there a way to build opencv_world with cmake? I need to use the xfeatures2d module to use SURF and also the world300.lib for my project. Since world300.lib and world300d.lib are available in the prebuilt libraries for opencv3.0.0 shipping from the opencv website and the xfeatures2d is in the opencv extra modules, is there a work-around to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Have you already tried to set the "BUILD_opencv_world" value in the CMake-GUI?

[image]

Do you have any error message?

Comment: I have done this above step, I am not able to build the ALL_BUILD project in VisualStudio if I check this option, without that, it builds fine.

Comment: The same behavior occurs for me with Mac OS 10.9.5, cmake 3.5.2, OpenCV 3.1.0, python 2.7.11.         https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6494